# Sudo command gets executed as root instead of specified user

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

```
sudo -EH -u someuser nohup sh check.sh &
```

Above commands runs the process as root instead of the user specified by -u flag.

```
root      4056  2388  0 13:00 pts/4    00:00:00 sudo -EH -u someuser nohup sh /tmp/check.sh &
```

Below are the sudoers entry.

```
Cmnd_Alias SUDO_CMNDS = /bin/echo,/bin/ls,/bin/cat,/bin/vim,/bin/mv,/bin/cp,/bin/rm,/bin/mkdir,/bin/diff,/bin/id,/bin/hostname,/bin/grep,/bin/nohup,/bin/locate,/bin/find,/bin/sed,/bin/awk,/usr/bin/whoami
```

%sudomygroup ALL=(someuser) NOPASSWD:SETENV: SUDO_CMNDS

Extra output as suggested by @michael homer

```
$ ps -ef|grep -i check 
root     14260 14090  0 13:20 pts/4    00:00:00 sudo -HE -u someuser nohup sh /tmp/check.sh
someuser    14261 14260  0 13:20 pts/4    00:00:00 sh /tmp/check.sh
```

Comment: Your second quote looks like it's reporting who ran `sudo`, not `nohup`.

Comment: Also, is the `&` really included in the output?

Comment: yes & is in the output .So how can i check who executed nohup

Comment: How did you check the one you quoted? See if there's anything more there.

Comment: I checked it using "ps -ef|grep -i nohup"

Comment: Try grepping for `check.sh` instead and you'll hopefully get multiple lines of output.

Comment: yes i got multiple line of output.what does this mean. can you explain.

Comment: Could you [edit] the extra output into the question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This line:

```
root 4056 2388 0 13:00 pts/4 00:00:00 sudo -EH -u someuser nohup sh /tmp/check.sh
```

is reporting that `sudo ...` was run as the root user. That happens because the `sudo` binary is setuid, and it's expected (regardless of which user asked `sudo` to run). What you're trying to find out is what user *the command that sudo then ran* is executing as.

Using `ps -ef|grep -i nohup` gave you only that single line of output, because when `nohup` runs it immediately shuts itself off upon executing the command it was asked to run, and then there's no `nohup` left in the `ps` output to grep for afterwards.

If you instead search for `check.sh`, you'll get (at least) two lines of output: the one you already see, and another one that's just for `sh /tmp/check.sh`:

```
root        14260 14090  0 13:20 pts/4    00:00:00 sudo -HE -u someuser nohup sh /tmp/check.sh
someuser    14261 14260  0 13:20 pts/4    00:00:00 sh /tmp/check.sh
```

That shows that the `sh` command *is* running as someuser, while `sudo` is just sitting there waiting for the inner command to finish, still running as root itself.

Comment: Yes, it does. The "inner" command `sh` is running as someuser, and the "outer" command `sudo` is sitting around as root waiting for the inner to finish.